# merge data from two different files in r

Tags: r

I have files with name `ABC_1`, `ABC_2` and so on. I am using the following code to read all the files from a folder.

```
s.name <- "ABC"
mylist <- list.files(folder.path, pattern <- glob2rx(paste(s.name,"_?.csv",sep="")), full.names=TRUE)
for (k in mylist){
  mydata <- read.csv(k,sep=",")
  attach(mydata)
  sub_mydata <- data.frame(x=mydata$VarA,y=mydata$VarB)
}
```

There is another `csv` file XYZ, that has a specific value for each of my `s.name`.It looks like

`XZY <- data.frame(s.name = c("ABC_1","ABC_2","ABC_3"),val = c(2,6,8))`

what I want inside the `for` loop is for the matching s.name, take the `val` and use it to calculate in `sub_mydata` as `z = mydata$VarC * val of ABC_?`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following with `lapply` -

```
s.name <- "ABC"
mylist <- list.files(folder.path, pattern = paste0(s.name,"_?.csv"), full.names=TRUE)

lapply(mylist, function(x) {
  data <- read.csv(x)
  filename <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(x))
  transform(data, VarC = VarC * XZY$val[match(filename, XZY$s.name)])
}) -> result
```